# joining phrase at correct place

Tags: clauses, subject-verb-agreement, run-on-sentences

I have following 2 statements.

> 1. The convergences of topological relations of adjacent segments can be
>      derived from graphs.
> 2. The convergences allows reconstruction of object
>      geometries with preserved topology.

I want to combine them to make a single sentence. I am struggling the placement to be linked this second sentence. I did as follows.

> **try1**: The convergences of topological relations of adjacent segments **can be
>   derived from graphs** *which allows reconstruction of object geometries
>   with preserved topology*.

But, I feel, this should be like

> **try2**:The convergences of topological relations of
>   adjacent segments, *which allows reconstruction of object geometries with preserved topology* **can be derived from graphs**.

Do you think that I placed the 2nd sentence correctly in try2? instead of **adjacent segments** can I use **segment adjacencies**?

Overall, what is good scientific writing style?

Comment: You can write like this : The convergences of topological relations of adjacent segments that allow reconstruction of object geometries with preserved topology can be derived from graphs..

Comment: I think a better writing style in general (scientific or not) is to not try to squish two already-complicated sentences together....  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Good scientific writing style favors shorter sentences. Keep to one idea per sentence.

> The convergence of topological relations of adjacent segments can be derived from graphs. This allows the reconstruction of object geometries with preserved topology.

*This* stands for “the convergence of topological relations of adjacent segments can be derived from graphs” or “the method by which the convergence of topological relations of adjacent segments can be derived from graphs”. I believe this is what you are trying to express. Your try1 expresses this idea.

However, if it is the convergences themselves that allow the reconstruction, in other words if a convergence is a mathematical object and this mathematical object allows the reconstruction of object geometries, then your try2 is correct, and the separate second sentence should start with “these convergences” or “this convergence”.

Note that I don't know the math well enough to validate these sentences: are they really relations *of* adjacent segments, rather than *between* adjacent segments? Should it be “convergence of a sequence of topological relations” or “convergence of a family of topological relations”?